# Go fish card transfer

Tags: c, linked-list

I have to create a go fish game in c. I have most of the brains working except the exchange of cards.

I have rewritten this a bunch of times, it works when I go step by step in a debugger but does not work when I run the program

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct card
{
    char suit;
    char rank;
};

struct player {
    struct hand* card_list;
    char book[7];
    size_t hand_size;
};

struct deck
{
    struct card list[52];
    int top_card;
};

struct hand
{
    struct card top;
    struct hand *next;
};

struct player user;
struct player computer;
struct deck deck_instance;

int add_card(struct player *target, struct card *new_card) {
    struct hand *end = (struct hand *) malloc(sizeof(struct hand));
    struct hand *tmp = target->card_list;
    end->top.rank = new_card->rank;
    end->top.suit = new_card->suit;
    end->next = NULL;

    if (target->card_list == NULL) {
        target->card_list = end;
        target->hand_size++;
        return 0;
    } else {
        while (tmp->next != NULL) {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
    }
    tmp->next = end;
    target->hand_size++;
    return 0;
}

int remove_card(struct player* target, struct card* old_card) {
    struct hand *new_hand = malloc(sizeof(struct hand));
    int new_count = 0;
    struct hand *tmp = target->card_list;
    struct hand *nextTmp = new_hand;
    while (tmp != NULL) {
        if (!(tmp->top.suit == old_card->suit && tmp->top.rank == old_card->rank)) {
            nextTmp->top.rank = tmp->top.rank;
            nextTmp->top.suit = tmp->top.suit;
            nextTmp->next = malloc(sizeof(struct hand));
            nextTmp = nextTmp->next;
            new_count++;
        }
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    target->card_list = new_hand;
    target->hand_size = new_count;
    return 0;
}

struct card *next_card()
{
    return &deck_instance.list[deck_instance.top_card++];
}

size_t deck_size()
{
    return 52 - deck_instance.top_card;
}

int deal_player_cards(struct player *target)
{
    if (deck_size() < 7)
    { // We don't have enough cards to deal
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        add_card(target, next_card());
    }
    return 0;
}

int shuffle()
{
    const char *suits[4] = {"S", "H", "D", "C"};
    const char *ranks[13] = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "T", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
    int suit = 0;
    int rank = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        deck_instance.list[i].rank = *ranks[rank];
        rank = (rank + 1) % 13;
        deck_instance.list[i].suit = *suits[suit];
        suit = (suit + 1) % 4;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        int j = rand() % 52;
        int k = rand() % 52;
        struct card c = deck_instance.list[j];
        deck_instance.list[j] = deck_instance.list[k];
        deck_instance.list[k] = c;
    }
    return 0;
}

void printDeck(struct player user) {
    for (int i = 0; i < user.hand_size; i++) {
        printf("%c%c ", user.card_list[i].top.rank, user.card_list[i].top.suit);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int transfer_cards(struct player* src, struct player* dest, char rank) {
    int result = 0;
    int hand_size = src->hand_size;
    for (int i = 0; i < hand_size; i++) {
        if (src->card_list[i].top.rank == rank) {
            result++;
            add_card(dest, &src->card_list[i].top);
            remove_card(src, &src->card_list[i].top);

        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int args, char* argv[])
{
    printf("Shuffling deck....\n");
    shuffle();
    deal_player_cards(&user);
    deal_player_cards(&computer);
    printf("Players 1's Hand - ");
    printDeck(user);
    printf("Players 2's Hand - ");
    printDeck(computer);
    char rank = '5';
    transfer_cards(&computer, &user, rank);
    printf("Players 1's Hand - ");
    printDeck(user);
    printf("Players 2's Hand - ");
    printDeck(computer);

}
```

The problem lives in add_card I believe. The rest of the code is just to get the c program to run

Right now I get this output

```
Shuffling deck....
Players 1's Hand - JC 5H 9H AH TD 3C AS 
Players 2's Hand - 4D 5D TS QC 6H TC 5S 
Players 1's Hand - JC 5H 9H AH TD 3C AS 4D 5D 
Players 2's Hand - 4D TS QC 6H TC
```

The correct output should be

```
Shuffling deck....
Players 1's Hand - JC 5H 9H AH TD 3C AS 
Players 2's Hand - 4D 5D TS QC 6H TC 5S 
Players 1's Hand - JC 5H 9H AH TD 3C AS 5D 5S 
Players 2's Hand - 4D TS QC 6H TC
```

Comment: That can be symptomatic of *undefined behaviour* somewhere in the code. When I run it (MSVC) it prints garbage for all except the first card in each hand: `Players 1's Hand - 9C  e Ú_  C  i  w  y` and `Players 2's Hand - 9H ÚR 6D ÚR 5C ÚR KS` and `Players 1's Hand - 9C  e Ú_  C  i  w  y  m` and `Players 2's Hand - 9H ‼[ 6D ‼] KS ‼_`

Comment: I use gcc and do not see that

Comment: That's how it goes with UB. It should not make any difference which compiler you use, or what debugging or optimisation options you use.

Comment: Ok, how do I deal with UB?

Comment: Well, the short and unhelpful answer is *"write well defined code"*. More helpful tidbits inlude things like *"Initialize everything when you define it"*, *"Be clear about the notional 'ownership' of heap allocated blocks in your code, and `free` when the owner goes away"*, *"Check return codes habitually"*, *"Null-test pointers before using them if you can't prove that they are good some other way"*, and so on. The list should include *"Allocate in automatic storage by preference to `alloc` family functions"* except that you can't avoid using the head for this assignment.

Comment: Why do you need a malloc() call in remove_card?  Since you want to remove it from a linked list all you should need to move the pointer (and free the removed entry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call deal_player_cards() -> add_card() and then check the value of target->card_list.  card_list and hand_size are not initialized as this point.  In deal_player_cards() you need to initialize the player structure before calling add_card().  This is causing the undefined behavior you are running into.

```
int deal_player_cards(struct player *target)
{
    target->card_list = NULL;
    target->hand_size = 0;

    if (deck_size() < 7)
    { // We don't have enough cards to deal
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        add_card(target, next_card());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There are other issues.  printDeck() assumes the the card list is an array.  However, add_card() sets it up as a linked list.  You can't assume that all the entries will be sequential in memory.  When printing them you need to traverse the linked list the same way you added cards to it.

```
void printDeck(struct player user) {
    struct hand *temp_hand;

    temp_hand = user.card_list;
    while (temp_hand != NULL)
    {
        printf("%c%c ", temp_hand->top.rank, temp_hand->top.suit);
        temp_hand = temp_hand->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately still junk in the dealt hands - different junk each run. Did you try it? The edit suggests not.

Comment: No I did not.  I just addressed the UB.  There is at least one other issue with printDeck().  I added it to my answer.